# how to access a specific value from a complex dictionary structure that has nested dictionary

Tags: python

i want to access a specific value from below dictionary and store it in a variable

```
{
  "filters": [
    {
      "variable": "cName",
      "params": {
        "default": {
          "values": [
            {
              "label": "dell",
              "value": "dell"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
....
}
```

for eg, need value dell and store them in an individual variables. like a = dell
i tried using get method to go to desired key value using indexes but still not getting desired output.
would appreciate a help in this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
(a,b,c) = (v["params"]["default"]["values"][0]["value"] for v in d["filters"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142458/218663) works perfectly, but you might also check out the `jmespath` package. With it, your required data could be found with the following pattern:

```
jmespath.search("filters[].params.default.values[].value", d)
```